# Text disappears when I shift js files into static folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I downloaded a HTML template and I'm trying to sort the files into respective folders while making sure the path names stay updated, but whenever I move the js file into the static folder, all my text disappears.

This is the initial structure of the downloaded template:

[image]

The `index - Copy` is a copy of the index file which I made because I didn't want to mess with the original code.

I created a static folder and tried to put the other static files in it one by one. I put the images file and it worked correctly. Bu the moment I put js file, all my 99% of my text disappeared and only 1 image out of a total of 3 images was displayed. What is happening?

EDIT: Updated file structure:

```
-app
    -static
        -css
        -fonts
        -images
        -js
    -templates
        -index.html
        -scss
        -.DS_Store
        -prepos-6.config
    -app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

The static files are linked to HTML using a relative file path. If you change the location of a static file, you also need to change the path in the HTML code.

For ex:

```
<script src = "/js/index.js"> //importing index.js
```

If you move the js folder to the static folder you need to change the path as well

```
<script src = "/static/js/index.js">
```

Comment: As I said, I did update the path but it is still not appearing.

Comment: Can you send the updated file structure as well as the index.html code?

Comment: I have updated the question regarding the file structure. You can download the original HTML file here and have a look at it's index.html code at - colorlib.com/preview/#digilab I also downloaded other such templates and realised that whichever template had these additional strange files (.DS_Store/.config files)ended up facing the same issue.